# How to extract HTML button and script content using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapy

I'm trying to scraping and I want to get the button and script content using python,
for example

```
<button class="xxx" href=www.example.com link="www.link.com"></button>
```

I want to print the class, href and the quoted link from the button tag,

```
<script> let x = 10; let y = 20; let link = "www.link.com"; <\script>
```

I want to get x, y and the link from the script tag, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<button class="xxx" href=www.example.com link="www.link.com"></button>
<script>let x = 10; let y = 20; let link = "www.link.com";</script>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

# print <button> stuff
button = soup.find("button", class_="xxx")
print(f"{button['class']=} {button['link']=} {button['href']=}")

# print <script> stuff
script = soup.find("script").text
x = re.search(r"let x = (\S+);", script).group(1)
y = re.search(r"let y = (\S+);", script).group(1)
link = re.search(r'let link = "(\S+)"', script).group(1)
print(f"{x=} {y=} {link=}")
```

Prints:

```
button['class']=['xxx'] button['link']='www.link.com' button['href']='www.example.com'
x='10' y='20' link='www.link.com'
```

Comment: thanks for your help, can I import the HTML page into html_doc using requests? because I want to create code to find an m3u8 URL using a URL website, **m3u8 sniffer**. the website is **"moviesub <dot> is"** and they put the m3u8 URL in the script tag inside the body tag **"data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1083.0"**, I tried to extract it but I don't know how.

Comment: @MohammedAlsahli You can open a new question here on StackOverflow, where you put what have you tried so far. I'll try to look at it.

Comment: @DevOps
am I mentioning you now?